# how to change hover for all elements ( border, text and arrow ) in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

how to change hover for all elements in react-select?

```js
<Select
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
```

[image]

Source host: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-8iq7b

Comment: Could you be more specific on what kind of result you expect ? thanks

Comment: border, text and arrow

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To customise your select, you can use the props `styles`. All the different components you can change are listed [here](https://react-select.com/styles).

To target specifically the `hover` state you should use the follow pattern:

```
const styles = {
    control: base => ({
      ...base,
      "&:hover": {
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    })
  };
```

Other options are available such as the `state` inside each `components` depending of what you're trying to achieve.

If you want all the elements to behave depending of the state of the `control` component you will have to write something like this:

```
  const styles = {
    control: base => ({
      ...base,
      "&:hover": {
        borderColor: "red",
        color: "red"
      }
    }),
    dropdownIndicator: base => ({
      ...base,
      color: "inherit"
    }),
    singleValue: base => ({
      ...base,
      color: "inherit"
    })
  };
```

You would probably also kill the animation `ease` depending of the speed of the effect. You can see a live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-w44cd).

Comment: and how you can do everything at once hover?

Answer (score 0):

```
  styles={{
                      control: (base) => ({
                        ...base,
                        border: `1px solid #e5e7eb`,
                        borderRadius: "0.5rem",
                        boxShadow: "none",
                        "&:hover": {
                          border: "1px solid #f6bf63cc",
                        },
                      }),
                    }}
```