# Issues with styling the <AsyncPaginate> in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I have tried several things, using tailwind CSS and some suggestion from internet,
But styling the AsyncPaginate component is too hard.

It has several default styling like border color when we select is default blue and the hover over the options of select have bluish tint and selection of any option make the bg color of that specific option blue, which I want to change, But not getting how!.

```
  const customStyles = {
    control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
      ...baseStyles,
      borderRadius: 15,
      boderStyle: "none",
      shadow: 2,
      borderColor: "#9e9e9e",
    }),
  };

  return (
    <AsyncPaginate
      className=" "
      placeholder="Search for city"
      debounceTimeout={600}
      value={search}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
      styles={customStyles}
    />
  );
```

I tried with customStyles variable and give it to the styles props but no luck.

Can anyone help me with it. Theres not much in docs too

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311202/how-to-change-hover-for-all-elements-border-text-and-arrow-in-react-select. The blue border colour btw is probably caused by the CSS `outline` rules which would be applied on `&:focus`

Comment: ```"&:focus": {
        borderColor: "purple",
      },``` 

I had tried adding this, but its still blue

Comment: What you want is `"&:focus": { outline: 'none', },`. `outline` effects are independent of borders (even though it looks like borders). If you wanted to make double sure you could try `"&:focus": { outline: 'none !important', },`

Comment: Or you could actually keep the `outline` but just change its color like `"&:focus": { outlineColor: 'purple', },`

Comment: ```"&:focus": {
        borderColor: "purple",
        outline: "none !important",
        outlineColor: "purple",
      },```

I tried but it still blue